# How to handle unique items under one category in MySql, where items may not be unique under different category?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Example:

```
category : food, bike, car
```

Items under category:

```
food = {rice, fish, beef};
bike = {Honda, Suzuki};
car = {Honda, Toyota, BMW};
```

here, 'bike' and 'car' different category can hold same items like 'Honda'. But neither category can hold same items.

Table name (column name):

```
1. category
-> id (primary, auto increment)
-> category_name (char, unique)

2. items
-> id (primary, auto increment)
-> item_name (char)

3. category_item_relation (many to many relation between table 1 and 2)
-> category_id (foreign key)
-> item_id (foreign key)
```

where `item_id` will be unique under same `category_id`, need to know the procedure in MySql.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? can you share the query you are trying?

Comment: It would be more helpful to see a table with sample data in it.  Short answer is that you should normalize your database, at least to some degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a unique key (or primary key) on the combination of category_id and item_id:

```
ALTER TABLE category_item_relation
ADD CONSTRAINT item_category_relation_pk
PRIMARY KEY (category_id, item_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

In that case you have to use Candidate Key. So you will have to create a unique key on combination of `category_id` and `item_id`

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the two preceding answers.

```
CREATE TABLE Categories (
    cat VARCHAR(...) NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY name
);

CREATE TABLE Items (
    cat VARCHAR(...) NOT NULL,  -- see Categories.cat
    item VARCHAR(...) NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(cat, item),
    INDEX(item)   -- possibly needed
);
```

*There is no need for the many:many relation table.*

It is just coincidence that two items in different categories have the same `name`.  Just like my name is `Rick James` (of category `super geeks`) and there was a singer named `Rick James` (of category `super freaks`).  There is no need for both of our names to coexist in a single row in any table.